# Error in MySQL Query: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; ..."

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently writing an API for my mobile application. When I was working on logout method I saw strange MySQL error:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1"

API request : *thapi.php?q=logout&user=1&session=aaa*

I tried to add *"* in SELECT statement, but it didn't solve my issue.

Here's my code :

```
 mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
 mysql_select_db(DB_BASE);
 $q = "SELECT * FROM `system_sesje` WHERE `sesjaid` = \"" + $_GET['session'] + "\" AND `user` = " + $_GET['user'];
 $a = mysql_query($q);
 echo mysql_error();
if(mysql_num_rows($a) == 0)
 {
  $returning = array('error' => 'Invalid session id');
  echo json_encode($returning);
  break;
 }
```

My table structure :

[image: HERE]

Comment: Look into SQL Injection. You need to use SQL parameters.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverFlow. [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: PHP uses the dot operator `.` for string concatenation, _not_ the `+`. That is a cause of your apparent problem, but your much bigger problem is the SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: @AmalMurali Yes, I understand, but I don't know objective PHP...

Comment: Also use `'` to quote your sql string values instead of `"`

Comment: @Musa: The quotes are unnecessary if he uses prepared statements...

Comment: @JanusTroelsen you probably mean bound parameters, but string values in mysql are single quoted(unless in ansi mode) and are never unnecessary.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski What I don't understand is, how can MySQL report an error, when the PHP syntax is wrong itself.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I also don't know...

Comment: @hjpotter92: Because the whole string evaluates to the integer one, which is converted to the string "1" and passed to MySQL? Try `php -r "echo 'a' + '1';"`

Comment: @hjpotter92 The PHP isn't invalid, it's just not producing the result intended.  Non-numeric strings will be cast to integer zero when used with a numeric operator like +.

Comment: @Musa: I meant [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), as it is the terminology of the manual. And string literals in MySQL can use [double quotes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-literals.html), but not in ANSI mode. You said "single quotes unless in ANSI mode", which presumably means they can't be single quoted in ANSI mode, which they can.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen by bad I was thinking about something else with the quotes. Also bound parameters require prepare statements but prepared statements doesn't imply bound parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments I solved the problem.

I changed :

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM `system_sesje` WHERE `sesjaid` = \"" + $_GET['session'] + "\" AND `user` = " + $_GET['user'];
```

to :

```
 $q = "SELECT * FROM `system_sesje` WHERE `sesjaid` = \"".$y."\" AND `user` = ".$z;
```

Now everything, works correctly. I added also a protection against SQL Injection :

```
$y = str_replace(' ', '', $_GET['session']);
$z = str_replace(' ', '', $_GET['user']);
```

Thank you very much !

Comment: A better protection for SQL injection would be to use `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Answer (score 1):

The [pdo](/questions/tagged/pdo) solution will be as follows:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_BASE;
$opt = array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    )
$conn = new PDO( $dsn, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, $opt );
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `system_sesje` WHERE `sesjaid` = ? AND `user` = ?");
$stmt->bindParam( 1, $_GET['session'], PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->bindParam( 2, $_GET['user'], PDO::PARAM_INT );
$stmt->execute();
if( $stmt->rowCount() == 0 ) {
    $returning = array('error' => 'Invalid session id');
    echo json_encode($returning);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
"SELECT * FROM `system_sesje` WHERE `sesjaid` = \"" + $_GET['session'] + "\" AND `user` = " + $_GET['user'];"
```

to

```
'SELECT * FROM `system_sesje` WHERE `sesjaid` = \"' . $_GET['session'] . '\" AND `user` = "' . $_GET['user'] . '"';
```

and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix for your query:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM `system_sesje`
        WHERE `sesjaid` = '{$_GET['session']}'
            AND `user` = '{$_GET['user']}'";
```

For the sake of your security, you must escape all your input values.

Comment: downvoted for putting the security in a footnote instead of in the code, where it belongs

Answer (score -1):

You could try writting your query like this:

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM system_sesje ";`

`$sql.= "WHERE sesjaid = '".$_GET['session']."' ";`

`$sql.= "AND user = '".$_GET['user']."'";`

I write queries this way so others can more easily get them. Watch for the spaces at the end of each line.